# EditText or InputText not working, create input method to get a string randomly

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-textinputedittext

I building an android application that has a floating button outside of the application(like Facebook chat heads messenger. the problem is that when I click the EditText or TextInputEditText it is not showing the keyboard.
I am new to android and I don't know if I can do this outside of the application. But I am sure there is a way to open the keyboard when the edittext is clicked to catch the float or string entered on the keyboard.
if there is a solution to get the real EditText working inside the service it will be awesome.

```
 @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    //getting the widget layout from xml using layout inflater
    mFloatingView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.widget_layout, null);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    } else {
        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    }

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;
    //getting windows services and adding the floating view to it
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    mWindowManager.addView(mFloatingView, params);

    initView();

    nameinput.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
            String david = imm.toString();
            Toast.makeText(FloatingWidgetService.this, david, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    //float button
    collapsedView = mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.layoutCollapsed);
    collapsedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //extended layout
    expandedView = mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.layoutExpanded);
    expandedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    closelayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    //close button
    mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.buttonClose).setOnClickListener(this);
    expandedView.setOnClickListener(this);

    //init


    //adding an touchlistener to make drag movement of the floating widget
    mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutParent).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private int initialX;
        private int initialY;
        private float initialTouchX;
        private float initialTouchY;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    initialX = params.x;
                    initialY = params.y;
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                    return true;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //when the drag is ended switching the state of the widget
                    expandedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    closelayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    return true;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    //this code is helping the widget to move around the screen with fingers
                    params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                    params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                    mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mFloatingView, params);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mFloatingView != null) mWindowManager.removeView(mFloatingView);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.layoutCollapsed:
            expandedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.nameinput:

            break;

        case R.id.buttonClose:
            stopSelf();
            break;
        case R.id.save:
            getparams();
            name = nameinput.getText().toString();
            textviewtest.setText(name);
            break;
        case R.id.closelayout:
            expandedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            closelayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: "WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE" maybe the reason, because that keyboard comes from OS itself, you dont need to trigger anything, but you disable focusing that will prevent that textbox or inputbox to get the focus which will result "keyboard not showing"

Comment: Thank you. I changed from FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE to ALPHA_CHANGED and it fixed everything.

Answer (score 1):

"WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE" maybe the reason, because that keyboard comes from OS itself, you dont need to trigger anything, but you disable focusing that will prevent that textbox or inputbox to get the focus which will result "keyboard not showing"